# R data.table apply function to sum of two columns

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I have a data.table, and I'd like to apply a function over its columns. Usually this is done like so:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, func), .SDcols = c("col1", "col2")]
```

And this would apply the function `func` over those two columns. What if, however, I'd like to apply it over the sum of those two columns? Something like

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, func), .SDcols = "col1 + col2"]
```

obviously doesn't work.

You could generalise this to applying `func` to the result of another function (in this case, `sum`) that takes in columns as arguments. I know I can create another column containing the results of the first function, but is there a way around that?

Comment: I usually "keep it simple" by creating that intermediary variable and remove later if I really have to get rid of it. Honestly, how long time (or extra memory) does it take to add that extra column with `data.table`? :)

Comment: @daroczig True, I'm just interested in saving a couple of lines of code and columns if the intermediate columns can be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

To add the columns, try

```
dt[, func(Reduce(`+`,.SD)), .SDcols = c("col1","col2")]
```

This works with more than two columns as well, adding them all together before applying `func`.

Comment: I see, nest the functions so that it becomes one function.